# Custom jms listener with apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, listener

I'm using Apache Camel and Apache ActiveMQ and need to react to connection closing/resuming.

I have tried to use `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` custom transportListener, but couldn't catch the moment when connection resumed. So I turned to custom `JmsListener`.

I configure component like this:

```
    private void setJms(String suffix) {
        ActiveMQComponent amqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
        Persistence persistence = AppBeans.get("cuba_Persistence");
        jmsConfiguration.setExceptionListener(e -> {
            log.debug("debug");
            persistence.runInTransaction(em -> {
                //actions
            });
        });
        jmsConfiguration.setConsumerType(ConsumerType.Custom);
        jmsConfiguration.setMessageListenerContainerFactory(MyMessageListenerContainer::new);

        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(count);
        jmsConfiguration.setPreserveMessageQos(true);
        jmsConfiguration.setTransacted(true);
        jmsConfiguration.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
        amqComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
        context.addComponent(connectionSettings.getJmsName() + suffix, amqComponent);
    }
////
```

and listener extending default - basically i just need to do something after resuming connection

```
    private class MyMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer {

        public MyMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint endpoint) {
            super(endpoint);
        }

        @Override
        protected void refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful() {
            super.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful();
            log.debug("WHOOOF!");
        }
    }
```

I can catch exceptions, but still have troubles with resuming. I get following messages:

```
MyMessageListenerContainer - Shutting down JMS listener container
MyMessageListenerContainer - Waiting for shutdown of message listener invokers
MyMessageListenerContainer - Still waiting for shutdown of 3 message listener invokers
```

Can somebody help me with my problem? Maybe there is another way to do some actions during exeptions/resuming connection to activemq?
Thank you.